# Dynamics 365 V9.0: unable to decode the error log

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365

I am facing issue with all the plugins in the production as they all are failing with below log.

```
    Unhandled exception: 
Exception type: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault]
Message: Expected non-empty string.Detail: 
<OrganizationServiceFault xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
  <ActivityId>xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx</ActivityId>
  <ErrorCode>-2147220989</ErrorCode>
  <ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
  <HelpLink></HelpLink>
  <Message>Expected non-empty string.</Message>
  <Timestamp>2019-07-29T12:36:40.3815746Z</Timestamp>
  <ExceptionRetriable>false</ExceptionRetriable>
  <ExceptionSource i:nil="true" />
  <InnerFault>
    <ActivityId>xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx</ActivityId>
    <ErrorCode>-2147220970</ErrorCode>
    <ErrorDetails xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
    <HelpLink i:nil="true" />
    <Message>System.ArgumentException: Expected non-empty string.
Parameter name: settingName</Message>
    <Timestamp>2019-07-29T12:36:40.3815746Z</Timestamp>
    <ExceptionRetriable>false</ExceptionRetriable>
    <ExceptionSource i:nil="true" />
    <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
    <OriginalException i:nil="true" />
    <TraceText i:nil="true" />
  </InnerFault>
  <OriginalException i:nil="true" />
  <TraceText i:nil="true" />
</OrganizationServiceFault>
```

As this is a limited message, I am not sure where to look.

Update 1: Earlier plugins were successfully executing, all of sudden it starts throwing exception. and I dont know where to find the field settingName, because this field is not there in any plugins or in any entity.

Update 2: 
Entity List:
 - Contact
 - Appointment
 - Task
 - Phone Call
 - CustomActivity

All the Plugins are registered for **Post-Operation** on either **Create** or **Update** Event

[image: System Job Log]

Comment: I guess the error is `<Message>System.ArgumentException: Expected non-empty string.
Parameter name: settingName</Message>`. But you should Google code `error 2147220989`.

Comment: Nowhere in the plugin I am using settingName attribute. Neither this field exist on any of the entity.

Comment: In that case reach tue plugin provider support, or re-install the solution.

Comment: can you add more details like entity, message, mode, and other environments experience, screenshot or more understandable context.. if any update happened to the org overnight, check with MS support ticket.

Comment: @Arun Updated the Question.

Comment: are you passing any parameter to your plugin? If so can you check it has been changed/deleted or so on.
Also can you Profile/debug your plugin?

Comment: Exception type of Organization Service Fault indicates that you are calling a method against the organization service with illegal parameters, specifically you are passing an empty string value where the service expects a non-empty value. Add some debugging logic and find out which service call is failing.

Comment: We had a priority ticket opened with Microsoft. It is happening across multiple organizations within the region, for now they restarted the Async Servers and now plugins are executing successfully. Waiting for RCA from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had a priority ticket opened with Microsoft for this issue. We got the RCA from them saying as

> Recent weekend deployment - Async machine went in invalid state and failing to deserialize the async context. They restarted the imapacted machine.